# Ruby bundle exec sidekiq does not work

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundle

When i am run ruby version 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14] and then run the command **bundle exec sidekiq** i am getting this error:

```
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: I think you may have encountered a bug...

Comment: Try upgrading or downgrading your ruby, and see if the error persist?